# Is there a special name for rejection of extremes in the list of cognitive biases?

Tags: bias

Is there a special name for the cognitive bias that causes a person choose a compromise solution even the extreme solutions are better or causes person prefer a middle value even the extreme values are more suitable?

Comment: conformism ....

Comment: In case you don't just want a name within phenotypical cognitive bias, this could be *reduced* to *degeneracy* emphasized by contemporary selectionists such as Edelman, where the dominant computational instructionists' point-to-point wiring would suggest universally statistically most people would prefer an extreme/optimized value for any perceived specific problem without the actual biological variation and diversity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [extremeness aversion](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s40622-018-0197-5):

> Extremeness aversion is the tendency of choice makers to avoid extreme
> options and choose an intermediate option.

This appears to be a well-replicated robust effect - see meta-analysis by [Neumann, Böckenholt, & Sinha (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcps.2015.05.005).